# Unable to listen with WSL2

Tags: go, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I've copy and pasted the "hello world" example from [here](https://yourbasic.org/golang/http-server-example/)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", HelloServer)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}

func HelloServer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}
```

And tried to run it on Ubuntu 20.04, installed on WSL2.

However, when I try to browse to 'http://127.0.0.1:8000', the server is not reachable.

To verify that this is not a port blocking issue, I ran `python -m http.server`

And the web page loaded correctly.

What might be the issue?

**===UPDATE====**

For some reason, browsing to

http://localhost:8000

Does work, an mentioned in this [thread](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4636)

Comment: Do you get any errors when you run the file,i.e, start the server?

Comment: No, it's running without errors

Comment: Don't ignore the error returned by [http.ListenAndServe](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe)

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4636 ?

Comment: what about http://localhost:8000?

Comment: OMG, it works, thank you.